# Using Pytest to test if a file is valid

Tags: python, python-3.x, unit-testing, pytest

I am brand new to python and know very little about testing.

**Background**

I am brand new to writing code in python and know little about testing. So as a first step I went through [PyTest](https://docs.pytest.org/en/stable/contents.html) document to get an idea of how to write tests. I have a basic idea of what fixtures are and how to use monkey patching etc. However I am a little stumped because I am unsure how to test my code as the given examples on the website not as practical.

**My Code**

```
class Cache:
    def __init__(self):
        pass

    def get_object_etag(self, s3_path: str, file_name: str) -> str:
        bucket, key = s3.deconstruct_s3_path(f"{s3_path}/{file_name}")
        return s3_resource().Object(bucket, key).e_tag

    def file_exists(self, local_path: str, file_name: str) -> bool:
        return os.path.exists(f"{local_path}/{file_name}")

    def cache_file(self, s3_path: str, local_path: str, file_name_on_s3: str) -> None:
        etag_value = self.get_object_etag(s3_path, file_name_on_s3)
        local_file_name = "etag_" + etag_value + "_" + file_name_on_s3
        if not self.file_exists(local_path, local_file_name):
            os.makedirs(local_path, exist_ok=True)
            s3.copy_with_python_retry(
                from_path=f"{s3_path}/{file_name_on_s3}",
                to_path=f"{local_path}/{local_file_name}",
            )
        else:
            print("Cached File is Valid")
```

I want to test the **cache_file()** function. This function will take the path of a file on s3, local path, the file name on s3 and append the etag value as a name. At any given time we can check if a path / file exists. In case the etag has changed then the file won't exist either since the local_file_name we construct would be invalid.

**Testing Approach**

Let's assume currently I have a path foo/myfoo/etag_123_my_file.csv/

Now let's say i go to s3 and for some reason the etag has changed so my file name becomes `etag_124_my_file.csv` so in this case i would fail the file exists check and be forced to download the updated file again.

Another test case would be the ideal case where the file name on s3 matches the local file name meaning the cached file is valid.

I am very confused on how I can test this as I am new to testing an pytest and don't have the test driven mindset.

For instance do i use monkey patch and just set attributes like the local_file_name and e_tag_value ? I would love it if someone can provide an example. It would help me a lot to get started in the testing world.

Comment: There are established ways for testing S3 - you may have a look at the post [3 ways to test S3 in Python](https://www.sanjaysiddhanti.com/2020/04/08/s3testing/).

Comment: @MrBeanBremen Thanks a lot, local stack looks promising. I can look in to that. If you have some experience by any chance can you provide further guidance on how my test should look like if i wanna test the cache_file() function meaning what should my test be doing?

Comment: got it that makes sense, would you be able to provide an example and post it as an answer i will be happy to accept that as an answer as it will get me started and then i can tweak and come up with different scenarios as you described above. Once again thanks for your time and effort.

Comment: @MrBeanBremen As i think more the other challenging part is that cache_file() does not really return anything explicitly so i am not sure how i would do an assertion?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Provided you mock all the S3 calls (with or without some framework), you could for example mock `file_exists` to return `False`, and check that `s3.copy_with_python_retry` is called, and in another test check the opposite (not called if `file_exists` returns `True`).

Here is a crude example (not using any framework) to show what I mean:

```py
from unittest import mock

import pytest

from s3cache import Cache  # assuming Cache is in s3cache.py


@pytest.fixture
def s3_mock():
    with mock.patch('s3cache.s3') as s3_mock:  # assuming you use "from boto3 import s3"
        yield s3_mock


@pytest.fixture(autouse=True)
def get_object_mock():
    # this is just for convenience - you mock the function as you don't test it
    # autouse=True means it is mocked in all tests
    with mock.patch('s3cache.Cache.get_object_etag') as object_mock:
        yield object_mock


@mock.patch('os.makedirs')
@mock.patch('s3cache.Cache.file_exists', return_value=False)
def test_s3cache_exists(exists_mock, makedirs_mock, s3_mock):
    cache = Cache()
    # you can put more sensible value here
    cache.cache_file("my_path", "local_path", "s3_fname")
    makedirs_mock.assert_called_once_with('local_path', exist_ok=True)
    # you can also check the arguments as above if needed
    s3_mock.copy_with_python_retry.assert_called_once()


@mock.patch('os.makedirs')
@mock.patch('s3cache.Cache.file_exists', return_value=True)
def test_s3cache_not_existing(exists_mock, makedirs_mock, s3_mock):
    cache = Cache()
    cache.cache_file("my_path", "local_path", "s3_fname")
    makedirs_mock.assert_not_called()
    s3_mock.copy_with_python_retry.assert_not_called()
```

As you don't want to test S3 functionality itself, you mostly have to check that it is called correctly, though you have to decide yourself what exactly you want to test.

Comment: can you clarify the use of s3cache i do not even have that lib and wondering why it is needed?

Comment: As I wrote in the comment: "assuming Cache is in s3cache.py". I don't know how your module is called, probably just `cache.py` instead.

Comment: This is great, just one last question. I understand how mock.patch works it is basically forcing a return value. I was wondering what the following assert_called_once() means and the other  assert_not_called() means is there a doc somewhere about them? I am thinking that i won't mock everything. I will only mock the file_exists return value as everything else is not as annoying to do including making an s3 call. so if that is the case how would i do an assertion to check when the python retry is called and when it is not?

Comment: See [the documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.mock.html?highlight=mock#unittest.mock.Mock.assert_called_once_with) for the `assert_called_` methods. As for using the real S3 for testing - ususally not a good idea for unit tests, but you can do it for integration tests. To check for all call you have either to mock the call, or check that is was called by it's effects.